# How to revert back in SVN force commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there a way to force commit in SVN?

Say I want to revert to revision 3 and now I am working on current version 5. I want to merge some of my changes done in revision 4 to 3 and commit revision 3.

Comment: What do you mean by 'force commit'?

Comment: And why are you trying to force it?

Comment: And why is the subject/topic question different from your post?

Comment: I don't see any difference in subject and question. How to force commit in SVN this is the question asked

Comment: Can you provide a use-case to try and help us work out what you mean?

Comment: Say I want to revert to revision 3 and now I am working on current version 5. I want to merge some of my changes done in revision 4 to 3 and commit revision 3. 

Am I clear

Comment: yes- I have the same question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For committing using Subversion, you should first update local files and then commit:

```
svn update
svn commit
```